# How to reformat time series to fill in missing entries with NaNs?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series

I have a problem that involves converting time series from one
representation to another.  Each item in the time series has
attributes "time", "id", and "value" (think of it as a measurement
at "time" for sensor "id").  I'm storing all the items in a
Pandas dataframe with columns named by the attributes.

The set of "time"s is a small set of integers (say, 32),
but some of the "id"s are missing "time"s/"value"s.  What I want to
construct is an output dataframe with the form:

```
id  time0 time1 ... timeN
     val0  val1 ...  valN
```

where the missing "value"s are represented by NaNs.

For example, suppose the input looks like the following:

```
time  id   value
   0   0      13
   2   0      15
   3   0      20
   2   1      10
   3   1      12
```

Then, assuming the set of possible times is 0, 2, and 3, the
desired output is:

```
  id   time0  time1  time2  time3
   0      13    NaN     15     20
   1      NaN   NaN     10     12
```

I'm looking for a Pythonic way to do this since there are several
million rows in the input and around 1/4 million groups.

Comment: You should construct a reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/463796) and give the expected output as well.

Comment: @w-m, is that example OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform your table with a [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html). If you need to handle duplicate values for index/column pairs, you can use the more general [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table).

For your example, the simple pivot is sufficient:

```
>>> df = df.pivot(index="id", columns="time", values="value")

time     0     2     3
id                    
0     13.0  15.0  20.0
1      NaN  10.0  12.0
```

To get the exact result from your question, you could reindex the columns to fill in the empty values, and rename the column index like this:

```
# add missing time columns, fill with NaNs
df = df.reindex(range(df.columns.max() + 1), axis=1)

# name them "time#"
df.columns = "time" + df.columns.astype(str)

# remove the column index name "time"
df = df.rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

Final `df`:

```
    time0  time1  time2  time3
id                            
0    13.0    NaN   15.0   20.0
1     NaN    NaN   10.0   12.0
```